# Finding the difference between the consecutive lines within group in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R. I have a data frame like following:

```
group start end
    A  34   77
    A  100  140
    A  185  246 
    B  60    98
    B  146   186 
    C  250   315
    C  411   489
    C  510   550
    C  601   662
```

I would like to find the difference between the consecutive lines as follows:

```
group start end 
    A  78  99
    A  141 184
    B  99  145
    C  316 410
    C  490 509
    C  551 600
```

Any little help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I get `100-34 = 66` and not 78.

Comment: Please elaborate on how you go from input to output.

Comment: I would like compute the start and end of the gaps between the entries within the group. For an eg in "group" A the start and end of the gap between first two entries is 78 and 99. Similarly the start and and end of the gaps between the second and third entry is 141 and 184 and hence so on.  In short I would like to find gap between the "end" of first entry(77) and start of next entry(99).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,.(start = (start+end - start +1)[-.N], 
           end = (end +shift(start, type='lead')-end-1)[-.N] ) , by = group]  
#   group start end
#1:     A    78  99
#2:     A   141 184
#3:     B    99 145
#4:     C   316 410
#5:     C   490 509
#6:     C   551 600
```

Comment: @Chudar Updated the post.  Please check if this helps